# Rails 5: loop through an array of records and indicate the new records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looping through an array of records like this:

```
@products = Product.where(category_id: @categories).order(updated_at: :desc)

<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <%= @product.title %>
  <%= @product.price%>
<% end %>
```

And now I wan to to mark the newest records as new releases:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <% if product.created_at <= product.created_at + 2.days %>
   New release
  <% end %>

  <%= @product.title %>
  <%= @product.price%>
<% end %>
```

But instead of going through each product and marking which ones is new (according to the if condition I have), it just takes the first record which returns true to the if condition and marks all of the products as new.

Any idea why this is happening and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is incorrect - this line:

```
if product.created_at <= product.created_at + 2.days
```

will always be true (you're comparing a date with itself), so everything will always be marked as a new product.

Did you mean to compare the created_at date with the current date instead? If you wanted to check if a product created less than two days ago, use `product.created_at >= 2.days.ago`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @sevenseacat. Yes that is exactly what I meant... to compare the created_at date with the current date! I tried this but the same thing happens?: `product.created_at <= 2.days.from_now`

Comment: That will find all products that have been created before two days time (older created_at dates are smaller values, and the date will never be in the future). If you want things created less than two days ago, try `product.created_at >= 2.days.ago`

Comment: Thanks @sevenseacat it works just fine. Update your answer so I can accept and up vote.